# Decodable DocumentReference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, decodable

I have a custom model in swift and it has a property of type `DocumentReference`
I'm getting some data from a cloud function and then I'm trying to decode it back to my model.

`DocumentReference` doesn't conform to Decodable by itself so I'm trying to write an extension for it.

I can not make it work since I keep getting this error:

> Initializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'DocumentReference'

Any idea how to make this work?

My extension:

```
import Firebase

extension DocumentReference: Decodable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //
    }
}
```

Existing model:

```
struct Notification: Identifiable, CollectionProtocol, DocumentProtocol {
    var id = UUID()

    var documentReference: DocumentReference
    var receiverID: String
    var type: String
    var createdAt: Date
    var requestReference: DocumentReference?
    var request: Request?

    init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.documentReference = document.reference
        self.requestReference = document["requestReference"] as? DocumentReference ?? Firestore.firestore().document("")
        self.receiverID = document["receiverID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.type = document["type"] as? String ?? ""
        self.createdAt = (document["createdAt"] as? Timestamp)?.dateValue() ?? Date()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(DocumentReference)
@interface FIRDocumentReference : NSObject

/** :nodoc: */
- (instancetype)init
    __attribute__((unavailable("FIRDocumentReference cannot be created directly.")));
```

`DocumentReference` (`FIRDocumentReference`) cannot be instantiated directly; it has no available initializers. To implement the required init, you'd have to do that in the declaration of the class itself.

If you want to conveniently instantiate custom objects from Firestore data, consider a failable initializer that takes a `[String: Any]` argument. If you just want to encode/decode the reference itself, consider encoding/decoding the `String` value of the location itself (the collection and document names) and then using that to reconstruct the `DocumentReference`.

Comment: so you mean to save the DocumentReference path as a string and then convert it back to a DocumentReference right ?

So instead of documentReference: DocumentReference to use sth like documentPath: String

Comment: @RexhinHoxha wouldn't a safer approach be to decode the collection and document names themselves and then use those values to reconstruct the `DocumentReference`? You can store the entire location as a single `String`.

Comment: I am not really getting it. can you provide some code please ? just a small example

Comment: @RexhinHoxha what is your ultimate goal with all of this? Let's avoid a potential XY problem.

Comment: I have an existing model (see updated question). now i have decided to use cloud functions and I want to decode the json response to an array of `Notification`. This models was intended  to work with `fetchDocument()` and  `fetchCollection()` but I want it tp be able to work also  with cloud functions (json)

Comment: I'd first rename the struct to something else; Swift already has a `Notification` object. I'd have to really dive deeper to help you with this; try posting another question with your next problem.

Answer (score 1):

The class DocumentReference is not final which means that it could possibly be sub-classed but without the sub class conforming to Codable. So this would leave to an unknown state if `init(from decoder: Decoder)` in your extension was called.

One workaround could be to create a wrapper struct with its own `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and then do your decoding of DocumentReference there.

Example:

```
struct Wrapped: Decodable {
    let docRef: DocumentReference

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder....

        // add the decoding code here for DocumentReference
    }
}
```

Comment: It it possible to provide a struct like this just to serve me as an example ?